# propensity score from logistic regression into MatchIT or other matching software in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I´ve created my own propensity score that I would like to match on. However, in order to match on the score I need to feed this score into a matching algorithm. I can do it using the **matching** library, but I would prefer to use **MatchIT** (due to covariate checks and Zelig). However, **MatchIT** and the other libraries (nonrandom, twang etc) seem to require that the library itself also produces the score for the matching procedure. Any ways around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `matchit()` function, if you have a vector `ps` of distance measures (e.g., your own propensity scores), you can use `distance = ps`. You'll get a warning, which you can ignore, and it will match on your distance measure.